# Find a general formula for the following product: $\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1-x^{2^{k-1}})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, products

Find a general formula for the following product:
$$S_{n} = \prod_{k=1}^{n}(1-x^{2^{k-1}})$$

I know how to evaluate the following product:

$$S_{n} = \prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+x^{2^{k-1}})$$
by multiplying both sides by $1-x$ everything simplifies and we get $\frac{1-x^{2^n}}{1-x}$ as the general formula for $S_n$.

What I was wondering is if we can find a general formula when we have an $'-'$ instead of $'+'$ sign. I tried applying the same trick, but it obviously doesn't work. I would appreciate if someone could give me their opinion.

Comment: I think it's the generating function of the Thue-Morse sequence. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence

Comment: $$\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(1-x^{2^{k}}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{t_{n}}x^{n}$$
Where $t_n$ is the n-th element of the said sequence

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the first time I hear about it.